# Prepare for segue function can't pass data to another VC Swift,

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to pass data from the alert text field to another VC's variable.
And here's my alert controller.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Download URL", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Download", style: .default) { (action) in
        
        guard let textField = alert.textFields?.first else {return}
        
        self.ayb = textField.text ?? "Blank"
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.ayb, forKey: "urlString")
        
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segAdd", sender: self)
    }
    let secondAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    
    alert.addTextField { (actionTextField) in
        actionTextField.placeholder = "Paste link here"
    }
    
    alert.addAction(action)
    alert.addAction(secondAction)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And here's my prepare function for passing data.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segAdd" {
        let destinationVC = tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] as? BrowserWebViewController
        destinationVC?.urlFromDownloads = self.ayb
        print("The value of destinationVC?.urlFromDownloads is \(destinationVC?.urlFromDownloads)")
    }
}
```

And in the console, it writes "The value of destinationVC?.urlFromDownloads is \Optional("Text I typed in textField")".

But in BrowserWebViewController my `"urlFromDownloads" is = ""(which is default)`.

Note: Segue's name is true.

Comment: What i thought is your segue.destination and your tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] are not same. Can you please try like ``` let destinationVC = segue.destination as? BrowserWebViewController.

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: From your answer, it seems your segue destination is Tabbar controller, not BrowserWebViewController. Can you please share a screenshot where segue is set in the storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all rather than declaring an extra property or saving the value to `UserDefaults` you can pass the string in the `sender` parameter

```
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Download", style: .default) { (action) in
    guard let textField = alert.textFields?.first else {return}
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segAdd", sender: textField.text!)
}
```

Your way to determine the destination view controller is wrong. Ask the `segue` for the `destination`. And you can force downcast the type. The code must not crash if the segue is designed correctly.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segAdd" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! BrowserWebViewController
        destinationVC.urlFromDownloads = sender as! String
        print("The value of destinationVC?.urlFromDownloads is \(destinationVC.urlFromDownloads)")
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows "Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x7fff898d0970) to 'Kiki.BrowserWebViewController' (0x10fe75120)" Thread 1 Singal SIGABRT.

Comment: As I said *The code must not crash if the segue is designed correctly.* Obviously it's not. Please show your storyboard or describe more in detail what you are going to accomplish.

Comment: Yes, it was my fault.